# setting 3000X2000 pixel image as canvas background without resizing and avoiding outofmemorybound

Tags: android, bitmap, out-of-memory, image-scaling

i was wondering if is  it efficient and possible to set 3000X2000px image as canvas background without resizing it and without getting the memory error.

because i want the real size image and pan around it.

using webview is not an option.

Currenty i tried to the set the background by using a folder structure named "Drawable-nodpi" and then assinging the bitmap image with decoderesource method.

Comment: You should look at previously asked questions like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4678331/how-to-tile-and-scroll-a-large-image-10000x10000-in-android). And you might want to do some research about tiling. :)

Answer (score 1):

Such a huge picture will inevitably cause outofmem exceptions on at least some devices. So I think that you need to dynamically scale and load only parts of the image that needs to be displayed, possibly with a caching mechanism.

Unfortunately, I don't know about any library components for Android that does this for you out of the box, but I'm pretty sure that you can find some nice articles on this topic.