# CATiledLayer alternative for Android?

Tags: android

For certain picture oriented apps I need to display big pictures and scrollable areas with further detail, once zoomed in.

In saw discussions and examples in iOS using `CATiledLayer`, which seems to do the job there.

Is there a CATiledLayer "port" or something similar for Android?

Comment: untested, maybe this is helpful: http://blog.gorges.us/2010/06/android-two-dimensional-scrollview/

Comment: Started doing one myself, pull requests welcome: https://github.com/ened/Android-Tiling-ScrollView

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This library seems to be very good:

https://github.com/moagrius/TileView

Answer (score 1):

I see you've started your own, but you may wish to check out [OSMDroid](https://github.com/osmdroid/osmdroid), which is a full-featured library that supports existing online map tile systems, as well as locally-cached tiles and a rich overlay API. It even supports mini-maps.