# How to improve the performance of ImageView when scrolling?

Tags: android, imageview

My app will generate a big `Bitmap` for pad,(it is about music score), then I use an `ImageView` to show the `Bitmap`, since the `Bitmap` is too long, so I use `ScrollView` to scroll the `ImageView`, I found it scrolling a little slowly. Is there a way to scroll the `ImageView` more smoothly?

By the way, my app just for pad. the `ImageView` almost occupy the full screen.

Comment: look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3058164/android-scrolling-an-imageview