# Android - How to set two ImageViews side by side and one of them scrollable in XML Layout file

Tags: android, android-layout

[image: preview]

ImageViews are of the same height. How to do this in XML Layout file?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3058164/android-scrolling-an-imageview

Comment: I prefer just to use ScrollView but I cannot set properly all elements.