# How to Create a 2D Map for an RPG Game

Tags: android, image, dictionary, scroll, zooming

I am working on a text RPG game for Android, and would like to create some kind of an area map for the player's reference. I Googled it but was directed to [Tiled.](http://www.mapeditor.org/) I am **not** trying to create a playable level map, just a basic map that the player can open to see areas explored so far for easier navigation. I would probably create these graphics myself using Fireworks.

The problem is a phone screen is only so big, and I need to somehow allow the player to swipe left/right/up/down to see all parts of the map. I guess on the biggest tablets perhaps the whole map would fit, but I need to support smaller resolutions as well.

So basically I think I need a way to display the map image in an activity (which I know how to do, duh), and allow the user to scroll around it because it will be way bigger than the screen.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3058164/android-scrolling-an-imageview

Comment: Oh, neat. Thanks alot mate. I see now that my question was not directed as it should have been :P