# How to set buttons in scrollable ImageView?

Tags: java, android, scroll, android-imageview

The first page "Candy Crush Saga Game" is a scrollable `ImageView` or not (what is that?). If that is a scrollable `ImageView` how to set buttons in that? 
Scrolling `ImageView` ex: [Android: Scrolling an Imageview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3058164/android-scrolling-an-imageview)

Comment: You can try to put the image view in a relative layout and set the touch listener on the relative layout. Inside the relative layout, above the image view add any button you like and it will scroll with the image view. Then you can set clickListeners on the buttons.

Comment: Can you post the code that you have tried?