# Draw circles on imageview before it loads and also image has pinch zoom option

Tags: android, imageview, pinchzoom

I need a Imageview which loads dynamically from server.
I have x,y positions where a small circles needs to drawn on the image at those positions.

Also this imageview should be having pinch zoom option where user can zoom in and zoom out along with the circle drawn. I have tried a lot of ideas from below links but unable to achieve expected output like below shown image

[Android ImageView Zoom-in and Zoom-Out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6650398/android-imageview-zoom-in-and-zoom-out)

[Android: Scrolling an Imageview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3058164/android-scrolling-an-imageview/26855091)

[image]

Comment: try this link for zoom and scrooling : https://github.com/chrisbanes/PhotoView

Answer (score 0):

try this link for zoom and scrooling : https://github.com/chrisbanes/PhotoView
and Use [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide) to load the image from the server and set your circle image into placeholder where its show until your  image is not loaded if you want different color than use this to create the circle color drawable

```
 val circleColorDrawable = try {
          DrawableUtils.getCircleDrawable(Color.parseColor("#here your color code"), 
      15.dpToPx())
       } catch (exception: IllegalArgumentException) {
        
               DrawableUtils.getCircleDrawable(Color.BLACK, 15.dpToPx())
          
       }
```